# Ajax responseText and statusText different on different servers

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, http

I have a project in ASP.NET MVC where inside an action I am returning the following :

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
       return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "custom err msg");
}
```

this response is send to the ajax function and catch by the fail() function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url to MyAction",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
  })
  .fail(function (data) {
    console.log(data); 
   });
});
```

When I run this through visual studio on local IIS Express, console.log(data) returns:

```
responseText
:
"some html with my 'custom err msg' inside it"
status
:
404
statusText
:
"error"
```

However on my Dev server which is Azure: it console.log(data) returns :

```
responseText
:
"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
status
:
404
statusText
:
"custom err msg"
```

why is it inconsistent like this? and what can be done so in both servers either my error message is in responseText or statusText

Comment: Have you checked the web.config settings for customErrors mode?  One server may have it on, while the other may have it off.

Comment: no that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

The status line does not exist anymore in HTTP/2. Maybe the servers are running different versions of HTTP?

(also, fwiw, there is no charset parameter on application/json)

Comment: "status line" you mean statusText?

Comment: yes, "status line" refers to what's in the http message, see https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#status.line